# how to change array auto key?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => bbb [2] => ccc )
```

this array, how to change to these two array?

A

```
array("name"=>"aaa","name"=>"bbb","name"=>"ccc");
```

B

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => aaa
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => bbb
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ccc
        )

)
```

Comment: If you don't set an index value as exactly you did and want to expect, PHP will set numeric index (auto key) for your array.
You already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(1. In the first array the indexes get set automatically starting with 0. 2. You have to have unique keys in your associative array)

```
<?php

    $arr1 = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    $arr2 = array("name1" => "aaa", "name2" => "bbb", "name3" => "ccc");
    $result = array();

    foreach($arr2 as $k => $v) {
        $key = array_search($k, array_keys($arr2));
        $result[$key]["id"] = array_search($v, $arr1);
        $result[$key]["name"] = $v;
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ccc
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, half an answer - must read the instructions...

The array with the same key of 'name' cannot be created as you would have an array with one row in it.

```
$arr = Array ( 0 => 'aaa',  1 => 'bbb',  2 => 'ccc' );

$outList = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $outList[$key]= array('id' => $key, 'name' => $value);
}


echo '<pre>Before: <br />';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>After: <br />';
print_r($outList);
echo '</pre>';


Before: 
Array
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => ccc
)

After: 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => ccc
        )

)
```